# How to add custom Info from my custom table in account information admin panel ? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-account, admin-panel

With ui component i can't add my custom data in there , maybe has a alternative ? 
I added the Customer Account Status, but I did it through InstallData.php, but I need to show there the text from the custom table
[image]

InstallData.php

```
    <?php
namespace CustomersState\AccountState\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_states', [
            'label' => 'Customer Account Status',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => true,
            'option' => ['values' => ['Active', 'Suspend', 'Vacations']],
        ]);
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Mohit Rane, i updated the question

Comment: you can set `'input' => 'select'` you will get your text data

Comment: i need other way without  InstallData

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my extension

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerAccountManager

Only difference is that the data is coming from a completely custom table and rendered on the frontend.

Hopefully there is enough there for you to understand what's going on.